# Modal not showing using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an Ajax call that calls in some settings, and I have them displayed on the site.

jQuery append call:

```html
$("#boxWrap2").append("<div class='col-md-4 box' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#TileBox"+object[i].TileOrder+"' id='TileBox"+object[i].TileOrder+"'><div class='titleBox'><h1>" + object[i].Title + "</h1><div style='width:250px; height: 130px;background-color: white; border: 1px solid lightgrey;'><img style='width: auto; height: inherit; padding-left: 10px;' src='" +  object[i].EncodedAbsUrl + "' alt='" + object[i].Title +"'/></div></div></div>");
```

---

**This will set the target as '#TileBox3'**
`data-toggle='modal' data-target='#TileBox"+object[i].TileOrder+"'`
[image]

---

When I click on the tile, it shows just a blank black screen with no modal popping up as below:
[image]

---

Modal code:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="TileBox3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><div id="x">&times;</div></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Acuvue</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="FT-main-category ms-WPBody">
                <div class="FT-main-header ms-WPBody">
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
                <div id="virtual-private-network-vpn">
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have two elements in your page with same id("TileBox3"). You should change that first of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is the id of the button you create  and id of modal are same "TileBox3"

```
<div class='col-md-4 box' 
data-toggle='modal' 
data-target='#TileBox"+object[i].TileOrder+"'  
          id='TileBox"+object[i].TileOrder+"'><---------change this
```

the data-target should point the id of modal (not the button as in your case)

for more info refer https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp